# Counting matrices of special types

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics

How many symmetric and non-symmetric $n\times n$ matrices with $0/1$ entries are there such that every row is distinct and every column is distinct? (I am looking for a proof as well).

If only every row (or column) is distinct is needed, the answer is easy.

As suggested in comments, https://oeis.org/A088310 provides the numbers without symmetric restriction. I do not see a proof or link for proof there.

What about symmetric case?

Comment: It's a good idea to look up OEIS first. A088310

Comment: For small $n$, I get the numbers of symmetric ones to be $4$, $44$, $716$, $24416$, which is a sequence not in the OEIS, nor are its obvious transforms (i.e. divide by 2 since we can swap 0/1).  [Not sure why the question has 2 votes to close, as it seems perfectly reasonable to me.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For generic (not necessarily symmetric) $m\times n$ matrices over a set of $k$ elements, the number of those with pairwise distinct columns and rows is
$$\sum_{i=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^n s(m,i)\cdot s(n,j)\cdot k^{i\cdot j},$$
where $s(,)$ are Stirling numbers of first kind with sign.

**UPDATE**. For symmetric $n\times n$ matrices over a set of $k$ elements, the number of those with pairwise distinct columns and rows is
$$\sum_{i=0}^n s(n,i)\cdot k^{i(i+1)/2}.$$

For k=2, numerical values for $n=1,2,\dots$ are
$$2, 6, 44, 716, 24416, 1680224, 229468288, \dots$$
and now form the sequence [A259763](http://oeis.org/A259763) in the OEIS. Just in case, I have verified these values for $n\leq 5$ by a direct enumeration of matrices.

Comment: How do you get the count?

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion but it's rather lenthty to post the proof here. I'll look at the symmetric case later.

Comment: ok is there 'main idea(s)' for the formula?

Comment: If one fix a permutation of rows $\pi$ and a permutation of columns $\sigma$, then the number of matrices invariant w.r.t. $\pi$ and $\sigma$ equals $k^{i\cdot j}$, where $i$ and $j$ are the number of cycles in $\pi$ and $\sigma$, respectively.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I don't think that your assertion about $k^{i\cdot j}$ is true. Let $k=2$, $\pi=\sigma=(1,2)$. Then the number of matrices invariant with respect to $\pi$ and $\sigma$ is four, not two.

Comment: @RichardStanley: I do not quite follow your argument. Matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ is invariant w.r.t. $\pi=(1,2)$ iff $a=c$ and $b=d$; and it is invariant w.r.t. $\sigma=(1,2)$ iff $a=b$ and $c=d$. So it is invariant w.r.t. both $\pi$ and $\sigma$ iff $a=b=c=d$. There are $k^1=2$ such matrices.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I meant that you apply $(1,2)$ to both the rows and the columns. I see that you meant something else.

Comment: @Turbo: I've addressed the symmetric case in the update.

Comment: Count is modulo row/column permutations right?

Comment: @Turbo: No, I do not take permutations of rows/columns into accout.

Comment: A closely related problem is that of counting graphs in which no two vertices have the same neighborhood. This corresponds to symmetric 0-1 matrices with 0s on the diagonal. These graphs are called point-determining or mating graphs. You can find links to their enumeration (both labeled and unlabeled) at https://oeis.org/A006024.

Comment: @IraGessel: Thanks for the pointer. It's interesting to see that "zeroing" the diagonal makes the problem much harder (apparently).

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: No, zeroing the diagonal doesn't make much difference. It just changes the $2^{i(i+1)/2}$ in $\sum_{i=0}^n s(n,i) 2^{i(i+1)/2}$ to $2^{i(i-1)/2}$.

Comment: @IraGessel: Yes, I've got confused by the complexity of the Gessel-Li paper. The formula is indeed a simple modification of what I posted here.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sketch of a simple derivation of the formula for counting symmetric $n\times n$ 0-1 matrices with every row and column distinct. (This is essentially the approach that  Li and I took in our paper, though since we also covered the unlabeled case, there are  more details.) This is equivalent to counting graphs, with loops allowed, such that no two 
vertices have the same neighborhood. Let $u_n$ be the number of such graph with vertex set $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and let $U(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty u_n x^n/n!$. Let $g_n=2^{n(n+1)/2}$ be the number of graphs (with loops allowed) on $[n]$ and let $G(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n x^n/n!$.  Every graph can be obtained from a graph with distinct neighborhoods by  replacing each vertex with a nonempty set of vertices, all with the same neighborhood as the vertex they are replacing. Then by the properties of exponential generating functions, 
$G(x) = U(e^x-1)$. Substituting $\log(1+x)$ for $x$  gives
$U(x) = G(\log(1+x))$ and expanding gives the formula for $u_n$ in terms of Stirling numbers of the first kind.

The same argument, with $2^{n(n-1)/2}$ instead of $2^{n(n+1)/2}$, counts graphs without loops with distinct neighborhoods (point-determining or mating graphs).